# PHP Mysql joins across databases

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

Lets say I have two separate databases, X and Y, on the same physical server.

All of my queries currently run out of X.

I find I have one table in Y I would like to be available to X for JOINS.

So... now I keep a copy of the one table I need for both X and Y in both X and Y, but the data in Y is constantly changing, so the copy soon becomes out of date.  Not critical for this application, but for another I'm designing now this just won't do.

X right now only needs read access to the table in Y.

Is there an efficient way to do joins across the two databases?

I'd prefer a mysql solution as opposed to opening multiple database connections in php.

Thank you.

EDIT:  So what becomes of these lines?:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
@mysql_select_db('database_name',$conn)
```

And yes.. this is an old app, hence the mysql instead of mysqli.  Suppose I could convert it.

EDIT2: So where I don't specify `database_name.table_name` and just specify `table_name` I get whatever is selected, and where I do specify `database.table_name` I get what I asked for.. right?  Yep.  Works.

EDIT3: Is there any significant performance hit by doing cross database joins versus joins within the same database?  Nope.  Looks just as  fast.

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: those lines remain unchanged. you still have to use mysql_select_db() because mysql requires an active db/schema before you can execute queries.

Comment: mysql_select_db() is actually not required. It just sets active default db, and you can do without it, if you specify the `db.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT:** So what becomes of these lines?:
>
> $conn =
> mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
> @mysql_select_db('database_name',$conn)

The mysql_select_db is optional.  As it just selects the active db to use.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

> And yes.. this is an old app, hence
> the mysql instead of mysqli. Suppose I
> could convert it.

IMHO I don't think using MYSQL has anything to do with being slow, from my own research into it, there is not much speed improvement with MYSQLi vs MYSQL.  Real world tests don't show that being a big performance driver.  I've honestly stuck with MYSQL for all my apps.

Comment: All my new apps use mysqli and prepared statements.  Repetitive stuff is faster, the rest about the same.

Answer (score 13):

you have to alias the table in the other database:

```
select a.id
     , b.foreign_id
  from database1.table1 a
  join database2.table1 b
    on b.foreign_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 4):

If the 2 databases are on the same server, you can simply qualify the table with the database name in the join query.

```
select * from database1.table1 as t1
 inner join database2.table2 as t2
 on t2.fk_id = t1.pk_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use SQL

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM foo f LEFT JOIN db2.bar b ON b.col1 = f.col1
```