# Can't select from SQL-View in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter, view

When I try this

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM WMY_VIEW WHERE id_bla = ? 
ORDER BY bla, blabla', array($bla))->result_array();
```

I'm getting this error

```
Query error: ERROR:  relation "WMY_VIEW" does not exist.
```

WMY_VIEW is a sql-view, not a table. BUT in regular php, it works

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WMY_VIEW WHERE id_bla=".$bla." ORDER BY bla, blabla";
$results = pg_query(CONEXION, $sql);
```

What's the problem with CI? What I'm missing?

PS: Database (`PostgreSQL`) it's not mine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355655/how-to-create-a-viewsql-in-codeigniter-and-select-data-from-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('id_bla',$id_bla);
$this->db->order_by('bla','desc');
$query = $this->db->get('WMY_VIEW');
return $query->result_array();
```